# How to provide power to a robot/raspberry pi?

Tags: mobile-robot, battery

I'm building a robot and powering it with a Raspberry Pi. I am looking at [this battery pack](http://www.adafruit.com/products/1566), but I am flexible with which one to use.

My problem is that I need to be able to charge the robot while it is still on, and apparently that is not good for a single battery pack to be charging while being used (they seemed to say so in the video). Am I wrong? Otherwise, how could I go about charging the robot while keeping the Raspberry Pi running?

**EDIT**: This is my first robot (other than my lego NXT kit), so I don't have any prior experience with robot batteries.

Comment: How do you plan to charge a mobile robot.like manually plugging the micro usb.

Comment: @HarpreetSingh I'm planning on plugging the battery pack into a wall outlet.

Comment: I don't think a usb battery pack would be best way.I think you should use a nimh, lipo, lithium ion any battery and use diode to switch between the two while charging one of them with a smart charger.

Answer (score 1):

[This](http://www.adafruit.com/products/1944) appears to be exactly what I need. It is a chargeable PowerBoost. It can charge a LiIon or LiPoly battery while it is being used to run a raspberry pi. I can then add several of these circuits to keep multiple things running. (So a powerboost for the pi, one for the servo controller, one for each powered USB hub, etc.) I can charge them using a power strip.

Answer (score 0):

I have an idea i used before.I got nimh battery around 7.2v. I used a usb module regulator that takes raw regulated or unregulated voltage and converts into 5v upto 3a [usb port](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B00M2NH1H8) I then charged it with constant current that was parallel with the battery and USB module via high power solar panels.

I will update this as I get more Information.